# Only number and dot character should allowed in UITextField in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

I am doing validation on my UITextField. It should accept only number and . character. Basically user can enter any decimal number like :

```
1.0
1.23
1.45
12.47
```

Also I have to add % sign while editing in textfield like below:

```
When User enter 1, textfield should update 1 %

When User enter 1.2, textfield should update 1.2 %

When User enter 18.345, textfield should update 18.345 %
```

I am using below Code to achieve this:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

    if string.characters.count == 0 {
        return true
    }
    do {
        if textField == self.questionTextFeild {

            let nString = textField.text as NSString?
            let newString = nString?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            let expression = "^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,8})?)?$"
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: expression, options: .caseInsensitive)
            let numberOfMatches = regex.numberOfMatches(in: newString! as String, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (newString?.characters.count)!))

            //textField.text = textField.text!
            if numberOfMatches == 0 {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    catch let error {
    }
    return true

}
```

Using this I can able to enter numbers and dot character. My problem is how can I add % sign? Please suggest me.

Comment: i think u tried this one is more than 3 days correct, what the exact OP you expect

Comment: I know, I am trying this from last 2 days and can't able to achieve. here also I am asking after searching everywhere in google. Can you please advise me.

Comment: sure , can you attach the sample project , i will try

Comment: Thank you so much @Anbu, But I am doing this directly to my app. I don't have any sample project.

Comment: okay give some time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171243/discussion-between-user2786-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

Please find the updated code for adding percentage to last of the number while typing

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

        if string.count == 0 {
            return true
        }
        do {
            if textField == textField {

                let nString = textField.text as NSString?
                let newString = nString?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
                if var textString = textField.text {
                    let unitString = " %"
                    if textString.contains(unitString) {
                        textString = textString.replacingOccurrences(of: unitString, with: "")
                        textString += string + unitString
                        textField.text = textString
                    } else {
                        textField.text = string + unitString
                    }
                }
                let expression = "^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,8})?)?$"
                let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: expression, options: .caseInsensitive)
                let numberOfMatches = regex.numberOfMatches(in: newString! as String, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (newString?.count)!))

                //textField.text = textField.text!
                if numberOfMatches == 0 {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return true

    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Vinodh for your time. It's not working correctly.. When I am entering 1 then it's displaying 1 %1

Comment: And also its taking dot (.) multiple time in input value like 12.32.32.5 %